# Problema ao adicionar o Diretorio da Image no banco usando ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Controller**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UploadImageMvc.Models;
using System.IO;

namespace UploadImageMvc.Controllers
{
    public class ImageController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Image
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Add(Image image)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image.ImageFile.FileName); 
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(image.ImageFile.FileName);
        filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
        image.ImagePath = "~/Image/" + filename;
        filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), filename);
        image.ImageFile.SaveAs(filename);
        using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
        {

            db.Images.Add(image);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        ModelState.Clear();
            return View();
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult View (int id)
    {
        Image image = new Image();
        using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
        {
            image = db.Images.Where(x => x.ImageID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return View(image);


    }
}
```

}

**View**

@model UploadImageMvc.Models.Image

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}

### Add

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add","Image", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data " }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Image

---

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            
        

        
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImagePath, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

```
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Model**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

// 
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace UploadImageMvc.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Web;

```
public partial class Image
{
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("UploadFile")]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

}

insira o código aqui